# new listview item duplicates action of first listview item when listview scrolls down?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I have button and progress bar(invisible) in listview. When button clicks it should disappear and progress bar should be visible and start running (**downloading from web server**) and when it is done with running button should appear again. Now when I click first item's button, the progress bar runs but if I scroll down until first item goes off screen I see progress bar running simultaneously with first item's progress bar on last item of listview. If I scroll up the first item's progressbar runs normally. It happens same if I click second item the the second last item of listview does the same. What is the problem and how could I solve it? Please help!!!

Here is my custom listview adapter with async task

```
public static class ViewHolder
{
public ImageView imgViewFlag;
public TextView txtViewTitle,txtProgress;
public Button imgAR,imgPDF,imgDown,btnDel;
public TextProgressBar progress;
public ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(activity);
public Database db=new Database(activity);
int position;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
final ArrayList<String> array=JournalArray.get(position);
final ViewHolder view;
LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

if(convertView==null)
{
    view = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.familylist_item, null);
    view.progress=(TextProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downprogress);
    view.progress.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    //view.txtProgress=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textProgress);
    view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    view.imgAR=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAR);
    view.imgAR.setTag(view);
    view.imgDown=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageDown);
    view.imgDown.setTag(view);
    view.imgPDF=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePDF);
    view.imgPDF.setTag(view);
    //view.progress=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downprogress);
    view.btnDel=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
    view.btnDel.setTag(view);
    convertView.setTag(view);

}
else
{
    view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

if(!isLoading){
if(DeleteBin){
    if(XMLParser.CheckFileInSD(array.get(5))){
    view.btnDel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.btnDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
else{
    view.btnDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(!XMLParser.CheckFileInSD(array.get(5))){
        view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
    view.txtViewTitle.setText(array.get(1));
    channelid=array.get(4);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramrel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/5,      height/5);
    paramrel.leftMargin = width/10;
    view.imgViewFlag.setLayoutParams(paramrel);
    view.imgViewFlag.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(new   File(array.get(3)).getAbsolutePath()));       
   view.imgDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(downloading<1){
        downloading++;
        path=array.get(5);
        channelid=array.get(4);
        pos=position;
        view.progress.setMax(100);
        view.progress.setProgress(0);
        view.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.progress.setText("Татаж байна...");
        new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, String, String>() {
            private ViewHolder v;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                v = params[0];
                int count;
                isLoading=true;
                //mprogress=progress;
                String result="0";
                if(view.cd.isConnectingToInternet()){
                    getChannel(channelid);
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(path);
                        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                        conection.connect();
                        // getting file length
                        lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                        String PATH="/mnt/sdcard/sdcard/.FamilyMagazine";
                        File dir=new File(PATH);
                        boolean test=dir.mkdirs();
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/sdcard/.FamilyMagazine/"+XMLParser.getFileName(path));
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                        long total = 0;

                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            // publishing the progress....
                            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                            // writing data to file
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        // flushing output
                        output.flush();

                        // closing streams
                        output.close();
                        input.close();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        result=e.toString();
                    }
                    }
                else
                    result="Интернетэд холбогдоогүй байна!";

                return result;
            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                // setting progress percentage
            view.progress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            int x=lenghtOfFile/100 * Integer.parseInt(progress[0])/1048576;
            view.progress.setText(x+"MB / "+lenghtOfFile/1048576+"MB");
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //view.txtProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downloading--;
               // if (v.position == pos) {
                isLoading=false;
                if(result.equals("0")){
                    view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.btnDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    view.imgDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.btnDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.imgAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.imgPDF.setVisibility(View.GONE);                           
                }
            }
          //}
        }.execute(view);
        }

    }
});

return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a view holder, the views are being re-used as you scroll down.  When using a view holder, you cannot assume your view starts in a specific state (GONE, VISIBLE, etc.) if you are changing it in certain rows.  You should explicitly set the state of your views every time.

Comment: please tell me where should I set state of my views. how can I avoid re-using?

Comment: problem occurs only during downloading process using asynctask. Everything works fine except when scroll down while downloading, I see the duplication.

Comment: I took all ViewHolder away and I'm still seeing the same problem